# How start New Activity when Click on Title Of HEADER_VIEW in RecyclerView To display items in IT

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDDXB.png)

In **Activty one** i have **RecyclerView** with to View :

- *HEADER_VIEW*
- *ITEM_VIEW*

Header_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#FFF7F7F7">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_group_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#F50057"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="More..." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Item_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/ll_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:elevation="3dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
            android:background="#f5fff2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="name"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#FF20C200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/new_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/old_price"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/old_price"
                android:text="480.00 DA"
                android:textColor="#FF65C2FD"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/old_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="250.00 DA"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#F50057" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/overflow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/new_price"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I created the Adapter and it Work Fine .

**My problem is :**

I need when I click on **more TextView** In HEADER_VIEW an New Activity Start

with Specific Itemes Of Stection.

**My try :**

In Adapter Exactly in **onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //Context context = mContextWeakReference.get();

    if (mContext == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (SECTION_VIEW == getItemViewType(position)) {

        final SectionViewHolder sectionViewHolder =(SectionViewHolder)holder;

        GroupTitleModel sectionItem = ((GroupTitleModel) mUsersAndSectionList.get(position));



        sectionViewHolder.title.setText(sectionItem.title);
        sectionViewHolder.more.setText(sectionItem.moreSection);

        sectionViewHolder.more.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


         // I TRY TO DO IT HERE BUT NO THINGS



            }
        } );


        return;
    }
```

Comment: So where do you store the list of item in a section, is it saved in `GroupTitleModel` class?

Comment: #Tam Huynh no i created tow view holder first itemViewholder ans second headerViewHolder ,GroupeTitelModel ils class of header it s containers titel of header an more string........ If you need i resend you all necessary code

Comment: Can you share the `GroupTitleModel` and the content model code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that you are bringing yourself into trouble by doing it this way.

You separate the `Header` view and its `Content` view, so the problem appear when the `Header` has no idea which content to continue to next step. If you don't want to refactor than it's ok, there will be a workaround. But my suggestion is that you combine the header and the content into 1 `ViewHolder`, keep the title, more text, and items inside 1 `Model` class too. They need to go with each other so they know how to handle with interaction

Comment: but i have tow View one for Header and second for item ....for that i create tow view holder

Comment: That's the problem I am talking about. Base on the image you designed: 1 Header row and 1 Content row are always going together, and they all present for 1 single purpose - a short info of 1 section. So I strongly recommend to combine them into 1 row only, you will only have 1 `ViewHolder`, 1 design layout, 1 model class and it won't be a hard problem to do what you've asked. Anyway, I will add a workaround solution if you need

Comment: THANK YOU!! You're right!! excuse me i need to give you +1 but i m new here +100 Thank you

Comment: Glad I can help